# Root Finding Function for upper and lower intersections of the x-axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, numerical-methods

I need to find the lower and upper intersections with the x-axis of a curve given by

```
y=f(x)=10⋅exp(sin(x))−(x^2)/2
```

In order to find the arc length of the curve, in Python

I have already tried two methods, The secant method which I cannot get to work at all. And the Newton Method which finds one intersection.

```
from math import exp 
from math import sin
from math import cos

def func( x ): 
    return 10*exp(sin(x))-(x**2)/2

def derivFunc( x ): 
    return 10*exp(sin(x))*cos(x)-x

def newtonRaphson( x ): 
    h = func(x) / derivFunc(x) 
    while abs(h) >= 0.0001: 
        h = func(x)/derivFunc(x) 

        x = x - h 

    print("The value of the root is : ", 
                             "%.4f"% x) 


x0 = -20 
newtonRaphson(x0)
```

which gives

```
The value of the root is :  -5.7546
```

Then the second method

```
import math 
from math import exp 
from math import sin


def f(x):

    f = 10*exp(sin(x))-(x**2)/2
    return f; 

def secant(x1, x2, E):
    n = 0; xm = 0; x0 = 0; c = 0;
    if (f(x1) * f(x2) < 0):
        while True:
            x0 = ((x1 * f(x2) - x2 * f(x1)) /(f(x2) - f(x1)));
            c = f(x1) * f(x0);
x1 = x2;
x2 = x0;
n += 1;
if (c == 0): 
    xm = ((x1 * f(x2) - x2 * f(x1)) /(f(x2) - f(x1)));
if(abs(xm - x0) < E):
    print("Root of the given equation =",round(x0, 6));
    print("No. of iterations = ", n); 
    print("Can not find a root in ","the given inteval"); 
x1 = 0; x2 = 1;
E = 0.0001;
secant(x1, x2, E);
```

Only results in

```
NameError: name 'x2' is not defined
```

Yet whenever I've tried defining the characters it won't run

I would like to be able to get the upper and lower intersections with the x-axis, So I can find the arc length. And is there a way to get it to plot the graph as well

Comment: Why did you not try to call the Newton method from different initial values? Please repair the indentation of the secant method, is this the error you observed? What is `xm` if `c!=0`?

Answer (score 1):

**About the Newton-Raphson method:**

*Normal behaviour*

It works mostly as intended. The method may converge to a single root only, which depends on the starting point. To get another root, you need another starting point.

Your function yields:

```
>>> newtonRaphson(-20)
-5.7545790362989
>>> newtonRaphson(5)
3.594007784799419
```

Which seems to be correct.

*Bugs*

The Newton-Raphson method isn't guaranteed to converge, it may enter an ifinite loop, in which case your program would hang indefinitely, or the derivative at a point may be zero, in which case you can't compute `h`. You need to handle these cases.

*Style*

There is a lot of things that can be inproved:

- The bug must be fixed
- You Newton-Raphson method currently only works for one function only. You should pass the function and derivative as arguments, so you can apply the method to any function you want.
- The desired precision and max iterations can also be passed as arguments
- It's bad practice to print within the function. You should return the value instead, so you can decide to do whatever with the result.
- you should follow PEP8's style guidelines
- include a docstring if you plan to reuse it (wich is very possible, it is a very useful tool!)

My take on the method:

```
def newton_raphson(f, df, x, epsilon = 0.0001, maxiter = 1000): 
    """ Estimates the root of a function.

    Gives an estimate to the required precision of a root of the given function
    using the Newton-Raphson method.

    Raises an Exception if the Newton-Raphson method doesn't converge in the
    specified number of iterations.
    Raises a ZeroDivisionError if the derivative is zero at a calculated point

    :param f: The function 
    :param df: The function's derivative
    :param x: the starting point for the method
    :param epsilon: The desired precision
    :param maxiter: The maximum number of iterations

    :return: The root extimate
    :rtype: float
    """

    for _ in range(maxiter):
        h = f(x)/df(x) 
        if abs(h) < epsilon:
            return x
        x = x - h 

    raise Exception("Newton Raphson method didn't "
                    + "converge in {} iterations".format(maxiter))
```

usage:

```
>>> print(newton_raphson(func, derivFunc, 20))
-5.7545790362989
>>> print(newton_raphson(func, derivFunc, 5, 0.1, 100))
3.5837828560043477
>>> print(newton_raphson(func, derivFunc, 5, 0.001, 100))
3.594007784799419
>>> print(newton_raphson(func, derivFunc, 5, 1e-9, 4))
Traceback (most recent call last):
(...)
Exception: Newton Raphson method didn't converge in 4 iterations
```

**About the secant method:**

I'm not as familiar with that one, so I'll just mention the error you have is due to bad identation. Here it is fixed:

```
def secant(x1, x2, E):
    n = 0; xm = 0; x0 = 0; c = 0;
    if (f(x1) * f(x2) < 0):
        while True:
            x0 = ((x1 * f(x2) - x2 * f(x1)) /(f(x2) - f(x1)));
            c = f(x1) * f(x0);
    x1 = x2;
    x2 = x0;
    n += 1;
    if (c == 0): 
        xm = ((x1 * f(x2) - x2 * f(x1)) /(f(x2) - f(x1)));
    if(abs(xm - x0) < E):
        print("Root of the given equation =",round(x0, 6));
        print("No. of iterations = ", n); 
    print("Can not find a root in ","the given inteval");
```

If you plan to propely implement this method, the remarks about the Newton-Raphson method still hold.